# Binding rangeslider to VM

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

here is a snippet of xaml

I have a few RangeSliders and I would like to bind the upper and lower values to my VM. Normally I attempt like below, but this has two different values per element name, how do I take care of this situation? I am new to this!

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="210" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1">
        <local:RangeSlider x:Name="sliderWind"
                           Margin="10" 
                           LowerValue="70"
                           UpperValue="120"
                           Minimum="0"
                           Maximum="160"
                           />
    </StackPanel>

    <Label  Content ="Wind Speed" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment ="Right" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Height="auto" Width ="auto" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=sliderWind, Path=LowerValue, StringFormat=N2}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="1,1,1,1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Height="30"  FontWeight="Bold" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=sliderWind, Path=UpperValue, StringFormat=N2}"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="1,1,1,1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Width="50" Height="30" FontWeight="Bold" />
```

view behind rangeslider

```
public partial class RangeSlider : UserControl
{
    public RangeSlider()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += Slider_Loaded;
    }

    void Slider_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LowerSlider.ValueChanged += LowerSlider_ValueChanged;
        UpperSlider.ValueChanged += UpperSlider_ValueChanged;
    }

    private void LowerSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        UpperSlider.Value = Math.Max(UpperSlider.Value, LowerSlider.Value);
    }

    private void UpperSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        LowerSlider.Value = Math.Min(UpperSlider.Value, LowerSlider.Value);
    }

    public double Minimum
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MinimumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));

    public double LowerValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(LowerValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LowerValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LowerValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LowerValue", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));

    public double UpperValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(UpperValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UpperValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UpperValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("UpperValue", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));

    public double Maximum
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(1d));
```

this is how I usually capture a value/value change in my VM

```
    private int _LowerValue;
    public int LowerValue
    {
        get { return _LowerValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _LowerValue)
            {
                _LowerValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LowerValue));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about `<local:RangeSlider ... LowerValue="{Binding LowerValue}" />` ? Or what is your actual question? You will need to define two source properties per `RangeSlider` element in your view model.

Comment: This might be of help: http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Creating_a_Range_Slider_in_WPF_and_other_cool_tips_and_tricks_for_UserControls_.aspx